# Assigning bool variable to another bool variable gives THREAD 1 BAD_EXC error swift 3

Tags: swift3, boolean

I first declare a variable methodType using this code

```
 var methodType: Bool? = nil
```

Then I go ahead and set this variable using a segmented control (also called methodType) like this.

```
else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell.methodType.isHidden = false
        cell.methodType.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
        switch cell.methodType.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0: methodType = true
        case 1: methodType = false
        default:
            break
        }
```

Then I go and set a boolean CoreData property = to the methodType variable like this.

```
 expense.cash = methodType!
 expense.credit = !methodType!
```

However, when I run the app, I get a THREAD 1 EXC BAD error for some reason? What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will first explain why the error occurs and then what your misunderstanding is.

In these lines:

```
cell.methodType.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment
switch cell.methodType.selectedSegmentIndex{
case 0: methodType = true
case 1: methodType = false
default:
    break
}
```

You set `cell.methodType.selectedSegmentIndex` to `UISegmentedControlNoSegment`. I think `UISegmentedControlNoSegment` is a constant value of -1.  Therefore, when you switch on it, it goes to the `default` branch as the selected index is neither 0 or 1.

So after running the above lines `methodType` is not set and is still `nil`.

Then you try to force unwrap it using `!`, which of course results in a crash.

You have misunderstood how to "bind" `selectedSegmentedIndex` to the variable `methodType`. One way to do this is as follows:

Replace the current switch statement with this call to `addTarget`:

```
cell.methodType.addTarget(self, action: #selector(methodTypeChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

Then add a method called `methodTypeChanged` to your class:

```
func methodTypeChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex{
    case 0: methodType = true
    case 1: methodType = false
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

You should also consider the case of the user not selecting anything. So when you are setting your core data property, you should check whether `methodType` is nil:

```
if let methodType = self.methodType {
    expense.cash = methodType
} else {
    // user hasn't selected anything. show an error message or use a default value.
}
```

Also, I think you should remove the `credit` property. It seems to always have the opposite value of `cash`, so it's not needed. You can know the value of `credit` just by accessing `cash`.